# Logged in as "undefined"

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So I'm going through some tokens i have for my discord bots and im trying to quickly see what token  belong to who. I was logging in with client.login() but when i use-

```
client.on('ready', () => {  
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}`);  
});
```

I get back "Logged in as undefined"
I'm not sure why it's doing this as i could login before using the same code.
Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance!
Ps. Sorry for bad grammar if there is any.

Comment: console.log(client) instead to see what you have in your object, that might give you a hint

Comment: could you please just help me? Its not like im new to this. I made [this](https://github.com/KraziDev/Izark-Utility-Source). I just need to get this one thing to sort my tokens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried

```
${client.user.tag}
```

and for some reason it now works. I think it was just my hosting.

Answer (score 0):

What is returned for the object client.user?
I assume that the client does not have any tags.
Just use `console.log( client.user );` to print content of the object.

Comment: this gives the id. <@709481960937881761> how can i get like... izark utility#5200

Comment: Okay, I just looked into the documentation. There should be a .tag variable. Could you just check that client.user.username returns the username correctly?

Comment: Yes i have ${client.user.username} and it has the name of the account

Comment: i guess thats good enough for me. Thanks. i gtg anyway im in school rn and im finna go to pe

Comment: As you want to store the user in a variable, you should save the whole client.user object, because the name could be the same for multiple users. The object, which you mentioned above (<@709481960937881761>), is unique.

Comment: can somone pls upvote my question?? I rlly dont want my first question to go negative